# Rblpapi BDH: How to output a single frame using security as a column?

Tags: r

I use following codes to get historical information for 2 stocks from Bloomberg.

```
library(Rblpapi)
opt <- c("periodicitySelection"="MONTHLY")
out1 <- bdh(securities = c("1 HK Equity", "2 HK Equity"),
        fields = "TOT_RETURN_INDEX_GROSS_DVDS",
        start.date = as.Date("2015-01-01"),
        end.date = "",
        options = opt,
        overrides = NULL)
out1

write.csv(out1, "c://R Data//TEST.csv")
```

Resulting csv file looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to get output file looks like this?

[image]

Comment: Please avoid screenshots and use `dput()` function instead, to provide data sample.